# Is it possible to restrict data using the WHERE syntax but on only one field not the entire SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Let's say you have a table called '**Companies**' that has the following fields: **Company_id**, **name** and you want to print out everything in this table but you also have another table called **emails** which has the fields: **data_key**, **data_value**, **company_id**. Now bearing in mind you want to print everything under companies but furthermore add whether or not they have emails - now if i wrote

```
Where data_key = email
```

Since I don't want to get any of the unnecessary data from emails - a WHERE clause would seemingly work but then it would discard all the data that doesn't have data_key = to emails, which i do want but only for the emails table not the Companies table

is there any way Around this
i would appreciate anything even a small hint

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Check out the WHERE EXISTS syntax.

Comment: Some sample rows and desired results would help.

Comment: Why do you have a table called "emails" that has something other than "email" in it?  Does that "emails" table, perhaps, have a unique constraint on (company_id, data_key)?  The answer seems obvious enough but difficult to say without understanding all of the factors.

Answer (score 1):

A subquery would be your friend:

```
select c.*,
(select count(*) from emails e where c.company_id = e.company_id) as email_count
from companies c
```

This will return everything from company, plus a count of emails for that company.

Or if you hate subqueries:

```
select c.*, count(e.data_key) as email_count
from companies c
left join emails e on company_id
group by c.company_id
```

The group by makes the left join not return multiple email rows per company.

Answer (score 0):

> but furthermore add whether or not they have emails

I haven't seen your dbschema, but you can join the table that contains your emails and use an if statement to define a boolean column to show whether or not they have emails:

```
SELECT 
    IF(Emails.data_key IS NULL, 0, 1) as has_email
    , Companies.* 
FROM Companies
LEFT JOIN Emails ON (Emails.company_id = Companies.Company_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do a `left join`, because that would introduce additional rows (if there were more than one email).  You could get around that using `select distinct`.

Here is another way to do it as nested selects:

```
select c.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from emails e on e.company_id = c.company_id and e.data_key = 'email'
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end) as HasEmails
from companies c;
```